# I am getting issue after update all plugin in Phone Gap Projects in Android Platform from Android Studio

Tags: android, phonegap

I am getting issue after update all plugin in Phone Gap Projects in Android Platform from Android Studio.

when i am trying to build the app that time i am getting this issue, for details please check my attached image .

Issue is:

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFV59.png)